# Cannot update, READ-ONLY - Visual Foxpro

Tags: cursor, append, visual-foxpro

This is my code

```
CURSORSETPROP("Buffering",4) 
SELECT course
APPEND BLANK
replace course.name with thisform.txt_course.value
```

this works fine during the development of the project, however,when i convert the project to .exe file, I cant write to the table and it brings the error

```
Cannot update the cursor course, since it is read-only
```

I've manage to find for what i thought was the solution which is the code below

```
CURSORSETPROP("Buffering",4) 
SELE * FROM course INTO CURSOR cCourse READWRITE
APPEND BLANK
replace cCourse.name with thisform.txt_course.value
```

But the problem is that this code does not write to the table. I mean there was no error about being the table read-only, however there are no additional file added/appended to the table "course"

Can anyone lend me a hand here, i have no idea where to find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vfp Error 111 itself, `Cannot update the cursor ...`, can be caused by a DBF table being included in the VFP Project Manager. If so, you can right click it in the PM and "Exclude".

There is however a mistake in the code you posted: The `CURSORSETPROP` line affects the alias in the current "work area", which could be anyone or even none, unless you would use the `cAlias` parameter of the function.

(Or, as a second best way, do the `Select` before the `CursorSetProp()`.)

Comment: LOL, its just so funy that i discovered this solution right before i check here again...hehe thank you by the way for explaining about the 'cursorsetprop' 
i have a working .exe now..thank you again...